# Let $x$, $y$, and $z$ be positive real numbers. Prove the following inequality...

Tags: inequality, real-numbers, means

**Question**

Let $x$, $y$, and $z$ be positive real numbers.  Prove the inequality:

A. $\frac{x^4+x^2+7}{y+2}+\frac{y^4+y^2+7}{z+2}+\frac{z^4+z^2+  7}{x+2}>=x+y+z+6$

B.
$\frac{x^4+x^2+7}{(y+2)^2}+\frac{y^4+y^2+7}{(z+2)^2}+\frac{z^4+z^2+  7}{(x+2)^2}>=3$

*idea*

So we have to show that

$\frac{x^4+x^2+7}{y+2}>=y+2$

And do the same thing to others.

We will be able to demonstrate the jnequality if we show this.

I thought of the inequality of means or the Minkovsky inequality but none of them works for me.

Also, we can suppose without lose of generality that $x<=y<=z$.

I dont know what to do forward. Hope one of you can help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By AM-GM $$x^4+x^2+7-(x+2)^2=x^4-4x+3\geq4\sqrt[4]{x^4\cdot1^3}-4x=0.$$

Thus, for A it remains to prove that $$\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{b^2}{c}+\frac{c^2}{a}\geq a+b+c,$$ where $x+2=a$, $y+2=b$ and $z+2=c$,

which is true by C-S:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{b}\geq\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{a+b+c}=a+b+c$$ or by AM-GM:
$$\sum_{a^2}{b}=\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a^2}{b}+b-b\right)\geq\sum_{cyc}\left(2\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{b}\cdot b}-b\right)=\sum_{cyc}(2a-b)=a+b+c.$$
Also, it's true by Rearrangement and there are many other ways to a proof.

For $B$  it remains to prove that $$\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{c^2}+\frac{c^2}{a^2}\geq3,$$ which is true by AM-GM.

Comment: Can you explain me better how you showed the second proof by AM-GM?? THANK YOUUU

Comment: @Ionela Buciu I added something. See now.

Comment: @Ionela Buciu Something is not true?

Comment: No. Everything its true. I was wondering how the point B can be solved. I tried doing the same thing by AM-GM but it doesn't work. It's one of my first time working with this time of problems so I'm sorry for being this puzzled.

Comment: @Ionela Buciu  I did not see $B$. Now, I added it.